# Google Site Search - help indexing pages with query string in page url

Tags: url, query-string, url-routing, google-custom-search

I've been utilizing a Google GSS instance for search on my site, and am having an issue getting pages that are generated using a query string to show in my search results.

Example of URL I would like to index:
    http://example.com/?geo=us&lang=en

Has anyone found a way to do this? The plain /faqs/ page does not give specified enough results, as the faqs are language-specific, thus the need. Setting up a redirect, such as

```
Redirect 301 /faqs/us/en http://example.com/faqs/?geo=us&lang=en
```

still won't index the page.

Notes:
On waiting for the indexing to happen - I have given the GSS instance over a week to normalize itself, and the pages still aren't showing
I have attempted on-demand indexing through http requests, adding the original and redirected urls to "sites to index", and on-demand indexing a single url.